# ES6 Class Variables Out of Scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Just made the switch over to ES6, running io.js.

I'm writing some class code, but I'm having an unexpected error.

```
'use strict';

var _ = require('lodash');

class Country {

  constructor(blocked) {
    this.blocked = ['USA'];
  }

  ok(input) {
    console.log('Receiving...',input['country']);
    console.log('Blocked:', this.blocked);
    if(_.includes('USA', input['country'])) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }

}

module.exports = Country;
```

For whatever reason, everything works well *except* for the `this.blocked` class variable.

When I console log it, it shows up as `Blocked: undefined`.

Any thoughts as to what's going on here?

**Addition**

I'm calling the function in another class as follows...

```
var Country  = require('./filters/country.js');
var country  = new Country();

class FilterClassifier {

    constructor() {
      var self = this;
      self.filters = [country.ok];
    }

    userFilter(params) {

      var self = this;

      var input = {
        country   : params.country,
      };

      console.log(self.filters[0](input));
    }

}

module.exports = FilterClassifier;
```

Comment: How exactly are you using the "ok()" function? Are you passing it as an event handler or something?

Comment: What if you do `var c = new Country(); c.ok([]);` - does it work then?

Comment: I'm calling it from a script. I don't think it should matter in this case though; since it's within the same class it should have access to the class variables (denoted by `this.var_name`).

Comment: That depends on whether the value of `this` is a reference to the instance or not, and *that* depends on how "ok()" is invoked. JavaScript does not work the way other languages work. The expression `this.blocked` isn't guaranteed to work.

Comment: Good point, Pointy! I've just added to the post how it's invoked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the way you are calling the function removed the context of the function.

```
self.filters = [country.ok];
```

and then

```
console.log(self.filters[0](input));
```

means that `this` inside `ok` will not be `country`. You'll need to do

```
self.filters = [country.ok.bind(country)];
```

or

```
self.filters = [() => country.ok()];
```

I'd recommend reading up on `this` in javascript. The short answer in this particular case is that `this` is defined based on how a function is called.

```
var a = {};
a.fn = function(){};

var b = {};
b.fn = a.fn;

b.fn();
```

When calling `b.fn()`, `this` inside the function is `b`. This is because when calling a function using the form `foo.bar()`, `this` inside a function is defined as the object that the function is called on (`foo`). In your case, you have

```
self.filters[0]();
```

that means that `this` inside your `ok` functions is actually `self.filters` for the same reason.

If you have a specific `this` that matters, it is your responsibility to make sure that as you pass around a function, that the function you are passing will set the proper `this`. Using `fn.bind(foo)` will return a new function which, when called, call `fn` with a given `this`.

Comment: This worked! Would you be willing to share a bit more about why this happens, and how I can avoid it in the future?

Comment: @DavidK. Expanded my answer a bit.

Comment: Great answer, Logan. Thanks for your help! Understanding that `this` is contextual in Javascript is hugely important for more complex applications.

Comment: BTW, if you're using already ES6, you can use [fat arrow functions(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to bind `this` to its lexical scope and avoid these issues.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `this.blocked` is scoped to the `constructor` function, `this` in `ok` doesn't have a identifier called `blocked`.

***Edit***: I was wrong, thanks Pointy.  In the interest of helping others who stumble on this post I'm not going to delete my wrong answer but instead share what I learned.  David, in the comments you asked for a way to fix it. `this` could be replaced with [let variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/javascript-let-keyword-vs-var-keyword) to avoid confusion or use `this` with `bind()` when a function is called.

```
class Country {

  // variable scoped to class with let
  // set blocked = value in constructor
  // should not need 'this.' nor 'bind()'

  let blocked = [];

... 
}
```

"[Determining `this`](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#determining-this)" says you had **default** `this` binding: undefined.  You hoped for **implicit** binding and got **explicit** binding to work with `country.ok.bind(country)`.

[Further reading](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/apC.md) illustrating how the fat arrow `=>` and `var self = this;` make `this` confusing.

Comment: No. `this.blocked` is a property reference for the instance.

Comment: Early examples probably used the syntax and it became the de facto convention.